# ionic <ion-slide-box> content view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm developing a mobile web application, the problem is that `<ion-slide-box>` does not show its contents.
`class="slider-slides"` has a width of 4096 pixels. if I set it to 0px and remove the `-webkit-transform :translate(-1366px, 0px) translateZ(0px)` property of `<ion-slide>`, the problem is solved but then I'm unable to scroll through contents.

this is my code:

```
<ion-slide-box auto-play="true">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="i in vimages" style="height:200px;width100%;" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <div class="box">
            <img ng-src="{{myURL+i.img}}">
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Comment: seems like issue is with css and not `ion-slide-box`.... show more css or add a plunker

Comment: I use default ionic css, I've not changed anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the $ionicSlideBoxDelegate's update method on data load callback or set a $timeout to execute it if using static data. It's a "feature" of Ionic that this must be done when using ng-repeat.

Comment: I've put $ionicSlideBoxDelegate's in my controller but it still doesn't work!